# Show that $(Z^\perp)^\perp=\overline{Z}$, assuming that $V$ is reflexive

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm stucked in the (c) item of the following:

> Let $V$ be a normed vector space and let $Z$ be a subspace of $V^\prime$. Define $$Z^\perp=\{v\in V;\ g(v)=0,\ \text{for all}\ g\in Z\}.$$
>
> (a) $Z^\perp$ is a closed subspace of $V$;
>
> (b) $\overline{Z}\subset(Z^\perp)^\perp$;
>
> (c) If $V$ is reflexive, then $\overline{Z}=(Z^\perp)^\perp$.

(a) and (b) are fine to me. However, I don't see how to use the fact that $V$ is reflexive to show (c). I find some proofs in the forum, but no one with this hypothesis.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there $y\in (Z^{\perp})^{\perp}$ which is not an element$y$ of $\overline{Z}$. There exists and element Let $f$ be the linear function defined on $Vect(y,\overline{Z})$ such that $f(\overline Z)=0, f(y)=1$, since $V'$ is Banach, by Hahn Banach, $f$ can be extended to $V'$ and this extension identified to an element $x\in (V')'=V$. We deduce that for every $z\in Z, z(x)=0$ implies that $x\in Z^{\perp}$, and $y(x)=0$ since $y\in (Z^{\perp})^{\perp}$. Contradiction since $y(x)=1$.

Comment: IMHO, this post needs an edit.